# Crashing while trying to import data from a file

Tags: c, file

I have a phonebook app that I am trying to give the functionality of being able to read and write files. I've figured out pretty easily how to write files, but reading them has really got me stuck. I think my main issue is the inability to get the file to loop(typically crashes as soon as it hits the loop). Below is my my effected functions.

Here are the structure, main, and menu functions.

```
typedef struct friends_contact{

   char *First_Name;
   char *Last_Name;
   char *home;
   char *cell;
}fr;
int main() {


fr friends[5];
char buffer[BUFFSIZE];
int counter=0;
int i=0;

menu(friends, &counter,i,buffer);

getch();
return 0;
}
//Menu function
void menu(fr*friends,int* counter, int i,char buffer[]) {
int user_entry=0;
int user_entry2=0;
char user_entry3[50]={'\0'};

printf("Welcome! Would you like to import a file? (1)Yes or (2) No");
scanf("%d",&user_entry);
if(user_entry==1)
     {

     file2(friends,counter,i,user_entry3);


     }else;
do{
     int result;

printf("\nPhone Book Application\n");
printf("1) Add friend\n2) Delete friend\n3) Show a friend\n4) Show  phonebook\n5)Exit\n");   
scanf("%d", &user_entry);


if(user_entry==1)
    {
        add_contact(friends,counter,i,buffer);
    }
    if(user_entry==2)
    {
        delete_contact(friends ,counter,i);
    } 
    if(user_entry==3)
    {
        result=show_contact(friends ,counter,i);
        if(result==0){
                  printf("\nName not Found\n");
                  }else{
                        result;
                        }

   }                  
   if(user_entry==4)
   {
       print_contact(friends, counter,i,user_entry3);
       file2(friends ,counter,i,user_entry3);

   } 
 }while(user_entry!=5);
   if(user_entry==5)
   {
      printf("Would you like to save entries to a file? (1)yes or (2) no");
      scanf("%d",&user_entry2);
         if(user_entry2 == 1)
         {
            printf("Please name your file");
            scanf("%s",user_entry3); 
            file(friends, counter,i,user_entry3);
            printf("Goodbye!"); 

         }else if(user_entry2 == 2){
            printf("Goodbye!"); 
       }
   }

}
```

Here is the function that handles the reading of the file.

```
void file2(fr*friends ,int* counter, int i, char user_entry3[50])
{

     FILE *read;

     printf("Please enter a file name");
     scanf("%s",user_entry3);
     read=fopen(user_entry3,"r");
    //This is where the crash is taking place!!**
     while(!feof(read)){
        fscanf(read,"%s %s %s %s",friends[i].First_Name,friends[i].Last_Name,friends[i].home,friends[i].cell);
        printf("\n""%s ""%s ""\n""<Home>""%s""\n""<Cell>""%s""\n",friends[i].First_Name,friends[i].Last_Name,friends[i].home,friends[i].cell);

      }
```

Now I understand there may be other problems with the program unrelated to what I'm asking, but I am new to C so this is a work in progress. I need to figure out how to stop this from crashing, and how to add this to the rest of my contacts(which I think I might have an idea for), it's driving me crazy! thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading data into undefined memory regions (you never assign any value to the 4 string pointers in your struct). I don't see you allocating memory for `friends[i].First_Name`, `.Last_Name`, `.home` and `.cell`.

You might want to change your struct like this:

```
typedef struct friends_contact{
   char First_Name[50+1]; // +1 for the '\0' terminating character
   char Last_Name[50+1];
   char home[50+1];
   char cell[50+1];
}fr;
```

Of course, if the file contains a part longer then 50 characters (including '\0' termination), your code will crash again, because `fscanf` will not check for the length unless you specify the maximum length for each string like this:

```
fscanf(read,"%50s %50s %50s %50s",friends[i].First_Name,friends[i].Last_Name,friends[i].home,friends[i].cell);
```

If you want to use pointers in your struct, you should allocate memory to each struct member using `malloc()` before the reading and use `free()` to release the allocated memory once you don't need it anymore.

Comment: As I said before this was a phonebook app, so there is definitely more to it then just these three functions. I have it to where to user can input contacts, and while doing this I use `malloc` and `free`. What your saying is I need to add another round of `malloc` and `free` for when the data is being read?

Comment: well if you don't allocate memory, those pointers are pointing to an undefined memory region, so yes, if you want to read data into those members, you first need to allocate memory for it. Read the data in it, print it out and free it again. But you might consider using strings of pre-defined length in the struct as I explained in my answer. It will save you a lot of trouble and memory leaks ;)

Comment: Could a memory leak be causing a weird infinite loop? I have it working where it reads the file and adds it to the contacts list, but after I view the contacts list, and then try and view the list again, it goes into a infinite loop.